# XSS check for angular js - REST based web application

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, xss

I have application which uses angular js on client side and makes ajax call to rest web service written in java.I want to apply xss check.
Can some one please suggest where it should be applied on angular js or rest web service side?and which library should be used?

Answer (score 1):

As per Angular -

> To systematically block XSS bugs, Angular treats all values as
>   untrusted by default. When a value is inserted into the DOM from a
>   template, via property, attribute, style, class binding, or
>   interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes untrusted values.

Please check on [Angular's security page](https://angular.io/guide/security) for more detailed `sanitization` example.